# universal use of ReflectionClass

Tags: php, reflection

Can I use PHP's `\ReflectionClass` without explicitly setting the class name?
My aim is to get class information inside its own context.

Instead of:

```
class Test {
    public function getSomeClassInfo() {
        $reflection = new \ReflectionClass('Test');
        // ...
    }
}
```

I want to do:

```
class Test {
    public function getSomeClassInfo() {
        $reflection = new \ReflectionClass({$this});
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the documentation of PHPs [ReflextionClass](http://www.php.net/manual/de/reflectionclass.construct.php) shows the class constructor accepts two alternate arguments: either a *class name* or an *object*. Since `$this` is a pointer to an object I'd say that should be possible. If not (give it a test!), then just use the generic class name constant `__CLASS__` instead.

Comment: Oh heck you are right. I must have read over that one. Thanks for pointing out and the alternative magic variable.